# Erro com controller no codeigniter com o nome system.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess, framework, controles

Estou mexendo em um projeto que está em CodeIgniter.

Existe um *controller* chamado `system.php` que é para acessar o `admin`, só que quando eu tento acessar ele dessa forma `localhost/meusite/system/método`, ele dá acesso negado porque pensa que eu estou tentando acessar a pasta system do CodeIgniter, mas se eu colocar assim `localhost/meusite/index.php/system/método` ele acessa normal.

O que eu não entendi é que o site que está no ar, está funcionando normal sem o `index.php` e aqui local ele não deixa.

Fui subir para o servidor de teste, e também não deixou.

Só está dando problema nesse *controller* por causa do mesmo nome `system`, o resto está funcionando normal.

Como eu consigo acessar sem precisar colocar o `index.php` e sem dar o erro de que estou tentando acessar a pasta `system`?

Segue meu .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque as pastas e arquivos do sistema do CodeIgniter fora da pasta pública (document root)

Exemplo

```
website/public/
website/public/css
website/public/js
website/codeigniter/[COLOQUE AQUI, POR EXEMPLO]
```

Após isso, defina o caminho do codeigniter no index.php que está na pasta pública, ou seja, na raíz do "DocumentRoot".

Comment: Vc diz para eu mudar a pasta system e application de lugar e colocar dentro de uma pasta exemplo codeigniter/system, codeigniter/application ?
Se for isso, não daria na msm ? Pq os controles estão dentro da pasta application.
Acho que não entendi o que vc postou '-

Comment: Pelo o que elucidou na questão, acredito que o conflito se dá porque os arquivos do CodeIgniter estão na pasta pública (document root).
Apenas coloque toda a estrutura de arquivos e pastas do frawework CodeIgniter num diretório acima do document root.

Veja esses links:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html

http://www.highermedia.com/articles/nuts_bolts/tutorial_advanced_codeigniter_installation

Comment: Vlws véy, era isso msm :)
Como não tenho acesso ao servidor de produção do site, não sei como o antigo programador fez, mas deu certo isso que vc me disse.
joguei assim codeigniter/system, codeigniter/application e foi.
Vlws O/

Comment: Boa taede @Daniel Omine, acho que estou com outro problema parecido com esse ai.Estou usando o Codeigniter e só a rota $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'; está funcionando, quando eu faço uma exemplo: $route['teste'] = "welcome"; ele me dá a seguinte mensagem Cannot GET /codeigniter/index.php/teste. Você sabe me informar como resolver isso ? essa pasta que contem o codeigniter está dentro de outra aplicação

Comment: Essa outra questão é muito localizada e foge do foco principal dessa página... Experimente criar outra questão explicando melhor o problema, com detalhes, etc... Mas acho que pode ter algo a ver com rewrite rule.